# Is it bad practice to have functions named evaluate_plural and evaluate_singular of the same word?

Tags: python

I have the function evaluate_models, which is passed a list of models, inside of which the function evaluate_model is called on individual models after preprocessing.

Would it be the better to make the names of these functions more clearly different?

The function is:

```
def evaluate_models(models, questions, num_res=25, score_num_res=10):
    dfs = []
    for model in models:
        df = evaluate_model(model, questions, num_res, score_num_res)
        dfs.append(df)
    return dfs
```

Comment: The answer you are looking for is 'Yes'

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the term `evaluate`? This could mean a lot of things.

Comment: Seems pretty reasonable to me, to be honest. If one is just a loop wrapper around the other, then the difference between them is just the plurality, so having vastly different names would lead to more confusion.

Comment: I added the function

Comment: `evaluate_models` doesn't really seem to be necessary; `evaluate_models(ms, qs, n, s)` would just be a wrapper around `[evaluate_model(m, qs, n, s) for m in ms]`. Not everything requires its own name.

Comment: (Alternatively, `evaluate_model(m, qs, n, s)` could be seen as a wrapper around `evaluate_models([m], qs, n, s)`. Pick one to implement, and leave the caller to deal with the minimal boilerplate necessary to handle the other case.)

Comment: Thank you. I just switched to your first suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aiming to write code that is easy to understand for everyone. Part of this is not making it overly obfuscated. So yeah, while it doesn't really matter, it's a good habit to do so.

Answer (score 0):

While the general style guide for Python, [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles), does not complain about similarly-named variables or functions, the general consensus would be to make it as easy to interpret as possible for someone else. If it's easy to miss the difference between the two function names, you should add more description to their names.